# Rails - Controller route with hostname parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two hosts my application gets deployed to

```
host1
host2
```

I want to expose a route that takes a host parameter to connect me to the correlating host. If I call `myapp/myendpoint/host1` I want to call the app on `host1` and vice versa, but I am struggling to write a route for this. I have tried:

```
get "controller/:host" => "controller#index"
```

But now stuck for how to handle the :host parameter in the controller and confirm it has hit the correct host.

Comment: In the controller, you can get access to the host as `params[:host]`.

Comment: ah yes,` params[:host] == Socket.gethostname` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, you can access `:host` with `params[:host]`.